# The car smoke is stink

Tags: grammar

A car went and the smoke flew in our house.

> "The car smoke is stink."
>
> "The exhaust smoke is stink.

He told me.

It should be car smoke or exhaust smoke when we telling someone the stink was came from the a car's exhaust?

Comment: We'd normally call them *exhaust fumes*. E.g.: [The car stank of liquor and regular exhaust fumes.](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=_0YUUs9oqfkC&pg=PA205&dq=%22exhaust+fumes%22+car+stank&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK1OrKrpjXAhUImJQKHdw4BsoQ6AEIKDAA)

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of your earlier question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/144144/the-giraffe-ear-is-fell-off  It is certainly close enough that you should have learnt from your earlier question.

Comment: If something smells bad, it's not correct to say **the thing is stink.*  You can say *the thing stinks* or *the thing is stinky.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Focusing purely on how to refer to the stuff that comes out of the car: "*exhaust smoke" is redundant, and sounds wrong to me. "car smoke" is okay, but isn't the idiomatic way to say it. In American English, better is "**car exhaust**" or just "**exhaust**" - that's the more typical way to refer to it.

Additionally, "is stink" isn't grammatical. You could say "stinks" (as a verb), or "is stinky" ("is" + adjective).

So, the closest American English match to your examples would be one of these two:

> The car exhaust stinks
>
> The car exhaust is stinky

Comment: Technically, I suppose "is stink" *could* be grammatical, if one understood "stink" as a mass noun. But it's definitely not idiomatic, except in certain varieties of slang usage.

Comment: Re "car smoke": the standard British way is "car fumes". For example, "The car's fumes stink" or "the car fumes stink".

Comment: AmE does sometimes use "smoke" to refer to abnormal engine exhaust: for instance, if it is burning oil, or coolant, or an excessively rich fuel/air mixture.  [Examples](https://www.bellperformance.com/blog/bid/115989/diesel-engine-problems-black-smoke-explained).

Answer (score 5):

If your doubt is whether to use '*car*' or '*exhaust*', then both sound fine to me, and I would know that you were referring to the smoke produced by the car, provided you say it at that moment, and I'm standing with you/ or am aware of the car that just went by.

But from the grammar point of view, I'll modify these sentence, a little bit, to make it sound better:

> - The car smoke stinks. (*Present*)
> - The car smoke is stinking. (*Present Continuous*)
> - The car smoke stank. (*Past*)
> - The exhaust smoke stinks. (*Present*)
> - The exhaust smoke is stinking. (*Present Continuous*)
> - The exhaust smoke stank. (*Past*)

You could also try "*The car's smoke ...*" and the "*The exhaust's smoke...*"

Comment: As a native AmEng speaker I would never say "the car's smoke" or the "exhaust smoke/exhaust's smoke." I would say "the car exhaust" (or just "the exhaust", "the fumes", the "exhaust fumes", etc.). It took me a second to draw the connection of "oh he means the *exhaust*".

Comment: That's true. Come to think of it, saying '_exhaust_' and '_smoke_' in a single sentence seems redundant. But exhaust may also be interpreted as the part of the car that produces the smoke.

Comment: Well if you're interpreting *exhaust* to mean *tailpipe*, the meaning is still clear. :)

Comment: Agreed that "car smoke" isn't the normal way to say it in AmEng. Now, I did figure out immediately what it meant, but that might be because I've spent a lot of time overseas.

Comment: _The smoke from that car stinks_ would be ok.  Agree that "car smoke" isn't normally what you would say.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to tell another person what has caused a smell, you could do it like this:

> That smell is car exhaust.
>
> That smell you're smelling is car exhaust.
>
> What you're smelling is car exhaust.
>
> You are smelling car exhaust.
>
> The odor you're smelling -- it's car exhaust.
>
> The stink comes from car exhaust.
>
> A car's exhaust caused the smell.
>
> The house reeks of car exhaust.
>
> The house smells like car exhaust now.

Answer (score 2):

> The **smoke** from that car stinks!
>
> The **smoke** from that car is stinky! (a more childlike way to say it)
>
> That car's **exhaust fumes** stink! ("fumes" are plural)
>
> That car's **exhaust fumes** are stinky!

So either "smoke (from a/the/that/this car)" or "exhaust fumes".

- [exhaust (noun)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exhaust#Noun) - a system for removing waste gases from an engine
- [fumes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fume#Noun) - a type of smoke or gas, e.g. also petrol fumes (gasoline fumes in the US)